# How to show tooltips every time at the top using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS as a library of choice to draw charts in the project. And cant figure out is it possible to force the library to show tooltip every time at the top of the chart? Because sometimes it shows tooltip to the top, sometimes to the bottom, sometimes to the left and right...

Would be nice to force it to show tooltip to the top every time.

I am using latest version of Chart.js which is 2.1.6 as of now.

Here is a playground on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gobakopohi/1/edit?js,output)

[image: screenshot]